# Sorting with special characters

Tags: php, sorting, special-characters

I have a function that sorst a list of values.

```
 function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
 }
```

It works great, but it is not sorting special characters with diacritics (ÁÉÍÓŮňďť etc.). These are listed at the end of the list even though they belong higher (proper sorting is like AÁEÉnň etc. but sorting makes it AEnÁÉň).

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this works for you, but what I usually do is cast the string to ASCII, which will therefore sort your characters as if they were "regular" vocals.

```
function build_sorter($key) {
   return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
       $stra = iconv('utf8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a[$key]);
       $strb = iconv('utf8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b[$key]);
       return strnatcmp($stra, $strb);
   };
}
```

Since we're transliterating to ASCII, you're getting the equivalent "A" for "Á" and therefore your sorter should now work properly.

- Remember to set utf-8 to the encoding of your choice. I just assumed it to be UTF.
- Your original strings are not affected.
- Sorting may be returning inconsistent results with strings like "alter" and "älter"

[These are problems English speakers never have]

Comment: Great, that worked, thank you very much! Trust me, I envy you that you don't have to deal with such things... :)

Comment: Hahaha. As a half German, half Spanish person who runs a website that is somewhat popular among Russians I got to deal with it. Feel your pain.